# Angular 4 outermost component class is not accessible to innermost class

Tags: angular

```
  app 
        ..... admin
               ..... CRUD
                         ....ADD
                         ....UPDATE
               ..... CRUDService
        ..... config
```

here CRUDService is not able to access config.ts
import { Configuration } from '.../'; 
                                 here 2 dots befors / gives to CRUD directory but after 3 dots if goes out of directory and shows jasmine,selenium etc files..

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using [barrel](https://chariotsolutions.com/blog/post/angular-modules-barrels-and-aot/) technique which doesn't seem to be working at your end. You have two options:

**While you are inside CRUD service:**

Inside your config directory, you should have index.ts file and `export * from './config'`

OR

Try using full path of config. In your case, it should be:

`import { Configuration } from '../config'`

Comment: import { Configuration } from '../config'; this one is not getting me config file...,,,,,,here is my config.ts contents                                       export class Configuration {
    public Server = 'http://localhost:3000/';
    public ApiUrl = 'api/';
    public ServerWithApiUrl = this.Server + this.ApiUrl;
}